# How can I check of an environment supports extending buildins like Array

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I would like to extend the native Array

```
class MyArray extends Array {}
```

However this feature cannot transpiled by Babel to es5. For my purposes it is sufficient to polyfill the Array class with an own version so that es5 users have still a valid object without native Array magic.

My idea is to check whether the environment supports extending native types and if so, use Array. If not, use the polyfilled Array.

How can I check if it is supported?

Answer (score 1):

On current Chrome this code reports `true`, but in Babel in es2015 mode it reports `false` because the transpiled constructor still returns a "real" `Array` object.:

```
class MyArray extends Array {};
let a = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log(a instanceof MyArray);
```